# Issue in understanding Crowsale in the ICO contract

Tags: ether, tokens, parity, ico, crowdsale

I want to create a token and run an ICO but all this without the function of crowdsale and minting. It want it to be a token which has a strict initial suplly (exmpl 1M) and without the funtion of minting so there cant be minted more tokens. But it has to have the functions of transfering it and looking up your balance.

The idea is that I have my own 1M tokens which I can trade and sell.

There are less information about that on the internet. My questions is:

Is this even possible?

### How can I do that or where can I get the information for that ICO?

/*
Implements EIP20 token standard: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md
.*/

pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

import "./EIP20Interface.sol";

contract BERToken is EIP20Interface {

```
uint256 constant private MAX_UINT256 = 2**256 - 1;
mapping (address => uint256) public balances;
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowed;
/*
NOTE:
The following variables are OPTIONAL vanities. One does not have to include them.
They allow one to customise the token contract & in no way influences the core functionality.
Some wallets/interfaces might not even bother to look at this information.
*/
string public name;                   //fancy name: eg Simon Bucks
uint8 public decimals;                //How many decimals to show.
string public symbol;                 //An identifier: eg SBX

function BERToken(
    uint256 _initialAmount,
    string _tokenName,
    uint8 _decimalUnits,
    string _tokenSymbol
) public {
    balances[msg.sender] = _initialAmount;               // Give the creator all initial tokens
    totalSupply = _initialAmount;                        // Update total supply
    name = _tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
    decimals = _decimalUnits;                            // Amount of decimals for display purposes
    symbol = _tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
}

function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value);
    balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
    balances[_to] += _value;
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value); //solhint-disable-line indent, no-unused-vars
    return true;
}

function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    uint256 allowance = allowed[_from][msg.sender];
    require(balances[_from] >= _value && allowance >= _value);
    balances[_to] += _value;
    balances[_from] -= _value;
    if (allowance < MAX_UINT256) {
        allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
    }
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value); //solhint-disable-line indent, no-unused-vars
    return true;
}

function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
}

function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value); //solhint-disable-line indent, no-unused-vars
    return true;
}

function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining) {
    return allowed[_owner][_spender];
}
```

### }

// Abstract contract for the full ERC 20 Token standard
// https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract EIP20Interface {
    /* This is a slight change to the ERC20 base standard.
    function totalSupply() constant returns (uint256 supply);
    is replaced with:
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    This automatically creates a getter function for the totalSupply.
    This is moved to the base contract since public getter functions are not
    currently recognised as an implementation of the matching abstract
    function by the compiler.
    */
    /// total amount of tokens
    uint256 public totalSupply;

```
/// @param _owner The address from which the balance will be retrieved
/// @return The balance
function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance);

/// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `msg.sender`
/// @param _to The address of the recipient
/// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
/// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);

/// @notice send `_value` token to `_to` from `_from` on the condition it is approved by `_from`
/// @param _from The address of the sender
/// @param _to The address of the recipient
/// @param _value The amount of token to be transferred
/// @return Whether the transfer was successful or not
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);

/// @notice `msg.sender` approves `_spender` to spend `_value` tokens
/// @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
/// @param _value The amount of tokens to be approved for transfer
/// @return Whether the approval was successful or not
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);

/// @param _owner The address of the account owning tokens
/// @param _spender The address of the account able to transfer the tokens
/// @return Amount of remaining tokens allowed to spent
function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256 remaining);

// solhint-disable-next-line no-simple-event-func-name
event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);
```

}

Comment: It sounds like you just need a very vanilla ERC20 token (no crowdsale or ICO contract necessary). Can you show us your code so far and tell us where specifically you got stuck?

Comment: Okay so I created a really basic token based on EIP20.sol and EIP20Interface.sol. It is basic. I defined the initial amount, token name, decinmal units and the token symbol. Then I deployed it. 

In order to trade with it I guess I need to add funtions like showing the balance, transfer an so on. I found a lot of info on the internet but it was only how to create a Crowdsale with a fixed price and minting coins. And I want a strict amount.

Comment: `transfer` and `balanceOf` are part of ERC20. Without seeing your code, I have no idea if you implemented them. If you're looking for  a simple token implementation, I have one here: https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/01/30/writing-an-erc20-token-contract/.

Comment: I posted the code under this question. I simply copied and pasted it in. On top you can see which .sol file it is. The name of the token is "BERToken". I posted the BERToken.sol and the EIP20Interface.sol . Look forward to see your opinion.

Comment: Please don't add "answers" that aren't answers. Are you unable to edit your question?

Comment: In any case, your code already has functions to transfer tokens and check balances. I'm not sure what more you're looking for. It should be possible to trade this token on any exchange that supports arbitrary ERC20 tokens.

Comment: Sorry Im new and didnt knew how to share the code. I changed it up. so you say that this enough. It dont any corrections or additional funcions?